# It suffices to check the skew-symmetry of a point-operator locally

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors, curvature

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold $E,F$ be $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ vector-bundles over M.

An $\mathbb{R}$-linear map $\alpha:\Gamma{(E)} \to \Gamma{(F)}$ is defined to be a pointwise operator iff whenever for some $s \in \Gamma{(E)}$ and $p \in M$ $s(p) = 0$ then $\alpha(s)(p) = 0$.

This is the Definition given in the book "Differential Geometry" by Loring W.Tu on page $53$.

Then in Prop.12.5 the author introduces a function
$\Phi:\mathfrak{X}(M) \times \mathfrak{X}(M) \times \mathfrak{X}(M) \times \mathfrak{X}(M) \to \mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ , $(X,Y,Z,W) \mapsto \langle R(X,Y)Z, W \rangle$.

where $R$ denotes the curvature operator. And claims that this function is skew-symmetric in $Z$ and $W$.

Now my question is: Why does it suffice to show this only locally, i.e. on some open set $U \subset M$?

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding what it means to check something locally. When someone states that e.g. continuity is a local property, it means that a function $f:X\to Y$ is continuous if and only if it is continuous on an open neighbourhood $U$ **around every point $x\in X$**. The same is true here. It does not mean that you can check the corresponding property on a single open subset.

Comment: Sorry I meant exactly that. My post was maybe formulated badly. I just don't understand where we use that we have a point-operator here. We check skew-symmetry pointwise and around any point then consider a triviaizing open set where we can write down sections explicitly and calculate the operator.

Comment: Then I do not see the problem. It's basically in the name "point operator", which implies that all you really need to know to determine its values at a point, are the values of the input at that point. In other words, if $p\in M$, you can shrink to as small a neighbourhood of $p$ as you want, and it will still give you the value of the point operator, because all the information from the larger open subsets is superfluous. If you do not understand why this is so, please edit your original post to formulate the question more clearly.

Comment: No thank you your explanation made perfect sense. I was just confused